# Why is concat adding time to the date when concat two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I am using pandas to get data from a sql query and json. I inspected both dataframes and the both have just the dates with no time. When I concat them it adds 00:00:00 to the date of one of the dataframes in the new dataframe. Why is it doing this. And is there a work around.

I am trying to join 2 dataframes and drop_duplicates but this prevents it from functioning properly by the date unless I specify other columns in the drop_duplicates.

Comment: Hi Eric, welcome on SO. Do you mind to have a read at [how-to-ask](/help/how-to-ask) and [mcve](/help/mcve) and edit your question accordingly?

Comment: Although I don't know why it's doing this I found a work around. in the concat df.astype({'date': 'str'}) prevented this from happening.pdjoin = pd.concat([pdhistory.astype({'date': 'str'}), pdtest.astype({'date': 'str'})])

Answer (score 2):

Although I don't understand the underlying problem with the concat adding 00:00:00 after the date of one of the dataframes this code in the concat fixed it

```
    pdjoin = pd.concat([pdhistory.astype({'date': 'str'}), pdtest.astype({'date': 'str'})])
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you post samples of your data?  Looks like one of the date columns is type 'string' and the other is type 'Datetime'.  If you convert both to Datetime, you'll be able to take advantage of the pandas rich (but complicated) date/time functionality.

Here is an example:

```
import pandas as pd
idx = ['2020-01-29', '2020-01-30', '2020-01-31']
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = [10, 20, 30], 
                   index=idx,
                  columns=['x'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = [11, 12, 13], 
                   index=pd.to_datetime(idx),
                   columns=['y'])
```

Now concatenate date-as-string and date-as-datetime:

```
print(pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1))

                        x     y
2020-01-29           10.0   NaN
2020-01-30           20.0   NaN
2020-01-31           30.0   NaN
2020-01-29 00:00:00   NaN  11.0
2020-01-30 00:00:00   NaN  12.0
2020-01-31 00:00:00   NaN  13.0
```

Convert date-as-string to datetime and concatenate:

```
df1.index = pd.to_datetime(df1.index)
print(pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1))

             x   y
2020-01-29  10  11
2020-01-30  20  12
2020-01-31  30  13
```

Advantages:  with date-as-datetime, you can resample (e.g., go from daily amounts to monthly amounts), make sensible time-series plots, etc.

Comment: I printed out both dataframes and they were displayed as just date before i concat them. One is from j-son other is from SQL Server. The SQL Server table column format is just date. I don't know how it does the j-son conversion. I will check the format of the column in each one and see whats what before I do the concat.

Comment: `df.dtypes` will give you info about the data type of each series.